# Excel INDIRECT Function Range not Valid

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

In a column, I´m storing ranges as plain Text.
I then want to use these ranges in a formula. As everything so far was in the same workbook I had no issue.
Now I want to get value from another workbook so I added just the path of the file just in front of my range.

It gives me something like that (stored in cell R38):
`'C:\Users\me\Documents\C251\[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251!'G4:G38`

Then I' m trying to use the following formula :
`MATCH("Stlnr.";INDIRECT(R38);0)`

But I got a ref error.
If I try the following :
`MATCH("Stlnr.";[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251!G4:G38;0)`
It does work.

I´m not sure what the issue is with my indirect function. And before you ask the other workbook is open. :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second apostrophe should be before the exclamation mark: `'C:\Users\me\Documents\C251\[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251'!G4:G38` and there is no point including a path given that it won't work unless the workbook is open. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem could be that when you enter

```
'C:\Users\me\Documents\C251[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251!'G4:G38
```

into a cell, Excel treats the first `'` as the symbol of starting a text field, so it thinks the path is `C:\Users\me\Documents\C251[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251!'G4:G38`.

Solution: Add a single quote either in the formula or in the data cell:

```
''C:\Users\me\Documents\C251[C251output_powereditor.xlsx]C251!'G4:G38
```

or

```
MATCH("Stlnr.";INDIRECT("'"&R38);0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the issue :)